# React native iOS Network request failed- issue with proxy settings

Tags: ios, react-native

I try to connect and get response in api through fetch request. Network request failed error has thrown.

My request is a `https` request.

I have proxy settings in both network preferences and bash_profile

Xcode info plist has `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` property.

In `postman` got the JSON response, but through RN code, request failed

I can connect with some other backend server and get response. But for this base_url only , got network request failed.

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("username", usernameValue);
form.append("password", encryptedPassword.toString());

return fetch(oAuthUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization' : authroizationHeaderField, //basic auth
    },
    body:form
})
.then(response => checkStatus(response))
.then(async (response) => {

    let responseJson = await response.json()
    return responseJson;
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error); //here error occurred
});
```

Can anyone please help or guide me to solve it.. Suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the method in following file. It allows any server with self signing certificate.

> RCTHTTPRequestHandler.mm

```
    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
```

Now the network failed issue is solved.